# Keep background in place while text scrolls

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a web page. I would like the top of my web page to have a full-screen image. When the user scrolls, some lines of text (a couple of headers) should scroll from the bottom to the top, the image staying in place. After scrolling through the headers, the user should be able to scroll past the image to the main content of the page.

Currently, I am able to get the full-screen image and overlay headers on top of it. I am unable to make the image stay in place while the user scrolls.

I am currently only using HTML and CSS, but I plan on using javascript and JQuery later down on the page, so I would be fine with using it here.

Current code:

```css
.fullscreen {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://moodle.fhgr.ch/pluginfile.php/124614/mod_page/content/4/example.jpg");
    background-size: cover;

}
.fullscreen-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color: white;
}
.fullscreen-wrapper h1, h2 {
    padding-left: 10%;
}
.fullscreen-wrapper h1 {
    font-size: 128px;
    padding-top: 25%;
}
.fullscreen-wrapper h2 {
    font-size: 256px;
    padding-top: 10%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Webpage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/home.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="fullscreen">
            <div class="fullscreen-wrapper">
                <h1 class="text1">Text 1</h1>
                <h2 class="text2">Text 2.</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

edit: The page doesn't look good in the small preview. Click "expand snippet"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few tweaks:

I think you better off keeping `.fullscreen`

```
position: relative;
```

Set the height on html, and body tag.

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

Set the 
`background-position: center;` to center the image

and

`overflow-y: scroll;` so you can scroll when you have more content.

See the snippet below:

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.fullscreen {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("https://moodle.fhgr.ch/pluginfile.php/124614/mod_page/content/4/example.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.fullscreen-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color: white;
}
.fullscreen-wrapper h1, h2 {
    padding-left: 10%;
}
.fullscreen-wrapper h1 {
    font-size: 128px;
    padding-top: 25%;
}
.fullscreen-wrapper h2 {
    font-size: 256px;
    padding-top: 10%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Webpage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/home.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="fullscreen">
            <div class="fullscreen-wrapper">
                <h1 class="text1">Text 1</h1>
                <h2 class="text2">Text 2.</h2>
                <h1 class="text1">Text 1</h1>
                <h2 class="text2">Text 2.</h2>
                <h1 class="text1">Text 1</h1>
                <h2 class="text2">Text 2.</h2>
                <h1 class="text1">Text 1</h1>
                <h2 class="text2">Text 2.</h2>
                <h1 class="text1">Text 1</h1>
                <h2 class="text2">Text 2.</h2>
                <h1 class="text1">Text 1</h1>
                <h2 class="text2">Text 2.</h2>
                <h1 class="text1">Text 1</h1>
                <h2 class="text2">Text 2.</h2>
                <h1 class="text1">Text 1</h1>
                <h2 class="text2">Text 2.</h2>
                <h1 class="text1">Text 1</h1>
                <h2 class="text2">Text 2.</h2>
               
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! The only issue (which isn't huge) is you have to take your finger off of the trackpad and scroll again when you reach the end of the image to get to the rest of the content. This isn't an issue on desktop, but on mobile, you have to completely take your finger off of your phone. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: No prob, I am not following what you mean by the scroll stops when it reaches the end of the image? The scroll is default browser scroll behavior and will scroll until it reaches the end of the content in `.fullscreen-wrapper` if the content height is less than the window height, you won't scroll. The scroll is not targetting the end of the image in any way.

Answer (score 0):

add you your `.fullscreen` this:

```css
background: fixed; 
background-position: top; /*or wherever you want to be fixed*/
```

also `overflow: auto;` will help you with the problem that the `.fullscreen` will be smaller than `.fullscreen-wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

No need for absolute position, just set background-attachement to fixed and avoid h1/h2 margins to keep wraper background in place.

```css
body {
    min-height:100vh;
    background:#ccc url(https://moodle.fhgr.ch/pluginfile.php/124614/mod_page/content/4/example.jpg) top center no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.fullscreen-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color: white;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.fullscreen-wrapper h1, h2 {
    margin:0;
    padding:1em 10%;
}
.fullscreen-wrapper h1 {
    font-size: 128px;
    padding-top: 25%;
}
.fullscreen-wrapper h2 {
    font-size: 256px;
    padding-top: 10%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Webpage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/home.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="fullscreen-wrapper">
            <h1 class="text1">Text 1</h1>
            <h2 class="text2">Text 2.</h2>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```